# Twitter webhooks: Can a sandbox package be used for production?

Tags: api, twitter, webhooks

I'm new to Twitter API. I want to build an app that requires users' activities via webhooks. In the doc page listed free (sandbox) and paid package. I'm not sure what it means.

Can a sandbox package be used for production?

It also shows the total maximum subscription for each package. What does subscription mean? Is it the total number of users that we subscribe to or get notification from?

Answer (score 1):

The "Sandbox" tier is fully production-grade... The main difference between the free version and paid versions is the number of Twitter accounts you can subscribe to the Account Activity API. The free tier supports up to 15 accounts.